# Exclusive Jersey Query Params

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Is there a way to acquire exclusive `jersey` `query params`? For example I have resource users, and I want to filter that resource by user login. So I want to have before, from and after login as 3 distinct `query params`. Only one of them can be specified at the same time.

Currently I'm just taking all of them as parameters, and have to `throw exception` manually on duplicate.

```
@GET
fun getTasks(
    @QueryParam("before") before: Optional<String>,
    @QueryParam("from") from: Optional<String>,
    @QueryParam("after") after: Optional<String>)
```

Is there a way to make my life easier? Ideally I would want it to work like this:

```
@GET
fun getTasks(@QueryParam("before|from|after") search: QueryParameter<String>)
```